# Loading once a list of cities in a "Preference" activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using a `Preferences` activity to list an array of cities.
For instance, this list is "hard-coded" in `res/values/arrays.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string-array name="cities">
     <item>Paris</item> 
     <item>London</item> 
     <item>Roma</item> 
     <item>Madrid</item>
   </string-array>
   ...
</resources>
```

This list is then called here :

```
<ListPreference
    ...
    android:entries="@array/cities"
    ...
```

Now, I want to load hat list from a web service :
Is it possible ? If so, how can I load that list only once the application is loaded and not every time the user launches the preferences activity ?

Regards,

Mick

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onCreate()` function of the activity to populate some global variable or an SQL table, then access it in the 'preferences activity'. Is that what you are asking for?